# Игра "Крестики нолики" через MVC

Tags: java

Народ, не обессутьте. Есть всеми известная игра "крестики нолики". Друг решил ее написать в качестве первого Android-приложения. И он решил игру писать через MVC. Так вот ответьте мне на вопрос вкратце, что будет делать модель, что контроллер и что представление. Где будет "зашит" основной алгоритм программы. Если что,не пинайте сильно)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, смотрите.

Модели у вас две: игровое поле и алгоритм игры (если компьютер будет тоже играть). Игровое поле умеет валидировать ходы и проверять выигрыш. Ну и знает, чей ход, наверное, и кто чем играет. Модель оповещает мир об изменениях игрового поля.

Представление рисует доску и обслуживающие меню, подписывается на изменения модели-доски и отображает их. Сообщает миру о действиях пользователя.

Контроллер запускает весь процесс: создаёт модель и представление, подписывается на нотификации о действиях пользователя, проверяет их на валидность у модели, и командует модели обновиться, запрашивает условия выигрыша, и в случае конца игры инициирует соответствующий UI.

В общем, всё как [здесь](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Comment: @VladD, Спасибо. Вы утвердили мое мнение по поводу ф-ций контроллера. Кстати, если несложно, опровергните обстоятельно мою позицию - я считаю, что писать ДЕСКТОПНОЕ приложение для данной игры через MVC - это усложнять себе задачу и не следовать принципу KISS. Может игра с MVC не стоит свеч?

Comment: @nightin_gale: Я обычно пишу вполне себе десктопные приложения под WPF/MVVM (MVVM — это такой вариант MVC), мне кажется, что так правильнее. Для небольшого приложения, наверное, полная реализация паттерна избыточна, но когда приложение станет расти и усложняться, без него не обойтись.

Это примерно как с классами: если проект маленький, можно обойтись вовсе без классов (если язык позволяет), но для сложных проектов классы становятся нужны.